# Best way to regrid data (polar stereographic to regular)

Tags: dataset, data, preprocessing

I have data that's in 'polar stereographic' form and I want to regrid it to a regular grid that matches a grid I currently have. I've seen a few example that tend to be fairly complicated. I'd ideally like something as simple as a command:

<regular_grid_data_i_want_everything_to_be_as.nc> <polar_stereographic.nc> < polar_stereographic_regridded_to_this_regular_grid.nc>

Does anyone know of software that is capable of regrid data/commands that do it in fairly simple ways?

Thanks!!